# Exclude files of being packaged in exe (vercel/pkg) with NodeJS / Express?

Tags: node.js, express, compilation, pug, exe

I developed a NodeJS project with the Express framework. I could successfuly compile my project in an ".exe" file with vercel/pkg.

How can I exclude a picture of my ".exe" to be able to change it after the compilation.

Furthermore, how do I define the path to this picture in my HTML code?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.

I tried to import my "external" folder like that:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "external")));
```

By doing this, the folder is packed in the ".exe" file during compilation.

The solution is to use the command "process.cwd()":

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), "external")));
```

This way I still have access to my "external" folder to change the files, but it is not included in the ".exe".

On my html/pug pages I now have access to my pictures in the external folder and I'm able to modify them if I want:

```
 div.View.WelcomeView
    div.ConnectionForm
        img.logoLogin(src="logo.png")
```